# NSDictionary from NSArray lose some values

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have to repair a developed app that use `NSDictionary` to show data when certain value is selected. But the problem is that this dictionary doesn't show all of the data that I pass to it.

In my situation I have 296 values per `NSArray`:

```
NSArray *departments = [aPerson.stringDepartment componentsSeparatedByString:@"--"];  // has 296 el.
NSArray *blocks = [aPerson.stringBlocks componentsSeparatedByString:@"--"];  // has 296 el.
```

I know that each `NSArray` has 296 values because I debug this app and see its values in Xcode Assistant Editor

Then here is the simple line that make me crazy:

```
self.depend = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:departments forKeys:blocks];  // has 291 el.
```

This just return 291 values

How can I make sure that every value ges to create a new key/value in my `NSDictionary`?

Comment: In a `NSDictionary`, keys are unic. I guess that some objects in blocks are repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `blocks` array has duplicates. `NSDictionary` is a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), thus it cannot contain two different values with the same key.

Comment: exactly that !! I never think they will has duplicate values before read your answer... my bad.. so Thanks a lot

Comment: Hash tables are not inherently unable to contain multiple values for the same key. See the "Collision resolution" heading at the link you've provided.

Comment: @JoshCaswell same key != same hash ;)